# Using a WPF controls own properties in Command Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, commandbinding

I have a ToggleButton. I'm using a command binding, and I want to pass the value of its IsChecked property as a parameter. How can I do this without naming the ToggleButton and using its name to address itself?

Currently I'm solving this by naming the control, but I assume this can be done a better way?

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="_myToggle" 
              Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_myToggle, Path=IsChecked}">
    Apply Toggle
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to use self binding :

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="_myToggle" 
              Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                         Path=IsChecked}">
    Apply Toggle
</ToggleButton>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Of course! Thx! Have done this before, but I had completely forgotten about it for a while there..